# dynamoDB query operation for array of strings checking using vogels node js

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, vogels

```
var arraTag = ["4"];
account.scan().where('tags').in(arrayTag).exec((err, data) => {
});
```

I am running above it showing empty data, but data is there in tag as 4.
By above query running i want where tags is 4 in table. that tags having array of strings.

Comment: what is the DynamoDB data type of tags? Is it List (L) or Set (SS)?

Comment: tags is a List (array of strings)